# Swift display image in webview

Tags: html, swift, image, webview

Using Swift with WebView:

I am creating html which I display in the webView control. The text html displays as expected but I am having trouble displaying and image which is in the project.(bundle) below is the code I have tried:

```
let urlpath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ld", ofType: "png");

webOut += "<img src='\(urlpath!)' height='16' width='16'>"
webOut += "<h3 style='color:#FD7D70ff'>\(sta.person!)</h3>"
webOut += "<div style='font-size: \(statementTextSize)'>\(sta.text!)</div>"

let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
webView.loadHTMLString(webOut, baseURL: requesturl as URL?)
```

the image does not display.

What is the best way to display an image in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two declarations for `urlpath` in your code snippet above - so I assume one was added in by mistake. But if I remove that and run your code, it runs fine and displays an image when I test here. So you might want to set a breakpoint in your code just before you call `loadHTMLString` and see what the HTML you are loading looks like and if perhaps it's valid HTML?

Comment: I removed the extra declaration and the html still display fine but the image doesn't show

Comment: Since the code does work here, I can only assume that the issue is something else. Is it possible for you to share the project with me so that I can take a look to see what is going on?